# How Do I Calculate Rolling STD Without Pandas STD or Mean functions?

Tags: python-3.x, std, mean, rolling-computation

I would like to incorporate Rolling STD into my Rolling Mean function.  I cannot use Pandas std due to the Nan values it produces.  I am unsure how to compute the sum of squares.  Any suggestions?  Do I need list comprehension?

```
def rolling_mean_std(x, wd_size=3):
    
    rolling_mean, rolling_std = None, None
    
    i = 0
    
    rolling_mean = []
    rolling_std = []
    while i < len(x) - wd_size + 1:
        if i<=wd_size:
            this_window = x[0 : 1 + i]
            
            window_average = sum(this_window) / (i+1)
            ##Edit to include std calculation
            window_std = sum((x - window_average) ** 2 for x in this_window)/(i+1)
            squirt=math.sqrt(window_std)
            rolling_mean.append(window_average)
            rolling_std.append(math.sqrt(squirt)) 
                
            i += 1
        else:
            this_window = ser[i : i + wd_size]
            window_average = sum(this_window) / wd_size
            ##Edit to include std calculation
            window_std = sum((x - window_average) ** 2 for x in this_window)/wd_size
            squirt=math.sqrt(window_std)
            rolling_mean.append(window_average)
            rolling_std.append(math.sqrt(squirt))
            i += 1
    
            
    return np.array(rolling_mean) #np.array(rolling_std)

alist = [2,4,5,7,9,10,21,89,43,90,13,100,1,45]
x = pd.Series(alist)

rolling_mean_std(x, wd_size=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Pandas `rolling` function and calculate the std of each rolling window, and append each std to a list to get the rolling standard deviations. Same for the rolling means.

For example:

```
wd_size = 3
alist = [2,4,5,7,9,10,21,89,43,90,13,100,1,45]
x = pd.Series(alist)

rolling_mean = []
rolling_std = []
for i in x.rolling(window = wd_size):
    rolling_mean.append(np.mean(i))
    rolling_std.append(np.std(i))
```